# FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile returns different strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, hash, sha1

I am doing a login page where I use SHA1 to hash password entered. I generate salt string. Add password to the generated salt string, and then hash it.

This is how I store values when I register. I store only the username, hashed password and the saltstring

```
string saltString = retSaltString();//This returns a salt string
string password = txtPassword.Text;
string saltPassword = password + saltString;
string hashPassword = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(saltPassword, "SHA1");
```

And when I authenticate user, I do the same in reverse:

```
string hashedPassword = //from database
string saltString = //from database
string saltPassword = txtPassword.Text + saltString;
string hashEnterPassword =   
FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(saltPassword, "SHA1");
```

But this time the hashEnterPassword is different and the login fails even for valid password. Why does the hashing generate different strings ? I started the project in 4.5 and since it said it no longer supports SHA1, I changed it to 4.0. Where am I going wrong ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: From this bit of code, the `saltString` looks like a suspect. Are you sure that the generation / storage / retrieval mechanism for the salt is working fine? I would begin by confirming that.

Comment: Even I started working on those lines. But when I debugged, the values retrieved while registering and storing in db and retrieving while logging in are the same